# Azure SQL Private Endpoint - can creating one cause downtime?

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-sql

Suppose I have an Azure SQL Database Elastic Pool and I am accessing it from an Azure Web App via Firewall rules and everything is working fine.

Now suppose I want to add a new Private Endpoint to the Azure SQL Database Elastic Pool.  This would NOT block access via the existing Firewall rules / access outside of the newly created Private Endpoint - is that right?

In other words, adding a Private Endpoint is not saying that access should now be Exclusive through the Private Endpoint but that the Private Endpoint is accessible and existing access channels are also still accessible - is that right?

Comment: I'm missing a bit of info:

Does the web app have a public endpoint at the moment?
Does the SQL Database have a public endpoint at the moment?

Am I correct in assuming that the connection string in the webapp connects to the public endpoint of the SQL Database?

Comment: @Dresse Yes, and yes.  Yes.  So the question really is, does *adding* a Private Endpoint, but not removing the public one, cause downtime on the public endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to carefully read the following article which basically answers your question.
By default, adding a private endpoint would not block access to the public endpoint but it all depends on the connectivity settings that are configured.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings